# How to find an inverse function of $\frac{2x+3}{x-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to find an inverse function of $\frac{2x+3}{x-1}$ step by step?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. What have you tried? Please show some effort!

Comment: Here's a start: Write $x=\frac{2y+3}{y-1}$ and solve for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$y(x-1)=2x+3$ thus $x(y-2)=y+3$, hence $x=\dfrac{y+3}{y-2}$. Now $y^{-1}=\dfrac{x+3}{x-2}$